# Make slug and menu location independant in GRAV cms

Tags: menu, content-management-system, slug, grav

Is it possible to have a simple URL like http://example.com/page_slug and add the page to whatever position I want in the menu especially a child position?

The problem is that whenever I attach a page to a parent menu, I got many levels in the slug like: http://example.com/parent/page_slug

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include the page header that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer [here](https://github.com/getgrav/grav/issues/1980).

With the option 'routes' in the header section, I can set a specific slug regardless of the folder name or the parent article.

```
routes:
    default: '/my_slug'
```